# How FB lite has size of only 465kb?

Tags: android

I use Android studio and if I just upload the blank "Hello World" project, my phone says it is 2MB in size. So that is 2 Megabytes for no content at all.

My question is how does [FB lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.lite&hl=en) achieve such small file size as 465KB? Are they using some in house software to make apps so small in size or there is a way to do that in Android Studio.

If someone could post some technical information on how they did this and give some sources for additional reading that would be great.

Comment: A better question would probably be "why is _my_ package so big?". You have access to your own package, so why don't you deconstruct it and see what's taking up all the space?

Comment: Check out [proguard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html)

Comment: MeetTitan I ran proguard this time. No luck.
SimonMᶜKenzie I have no idea. Its literally blank. I just created a new project and generated apk.

Comment: Rename it to .zip and open it...

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie I noticed two things. The .apk file on my computer is 689KB but on my phone (after installation) it shows 2MB. 

The res folder is 100-ish KB, "classes.dex" is 300KB and "resources.arc" is another 100-ish KB. How is this possible? I did not add any classes its just the bare bones!

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie Can you explain your view ? Rename it to .zip and open it

Comment: @AshishShukla, an apk is a zip file, so you can unzip it to look inside. Renaming to .zip just makes it easier to unzip, but certainly isn't necessary. Souradeep, maybe it's just the compression. Unzipping the apk will help you to clarify this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(According to my last experience using android studio) When you create a new project, it includes some libraries to help you create some "default graphics" (of buttons, sliders etc etc) these libraries are what costs you ~1-2 MB.

A simple "Hello World" app can be like 20-30kb or maybe less.

Edit: Forgot to actually answer

I'd guess the only thing the facebook lite app does is connect to the website, and everything else is handled there, so the app can have a size of 465kb without problem.